# how do i change the code to delete all records from the database and not one?

Tags: node.js, methods, nestjs

Here is the code to delete the record by id:

```
@ApiImplicitParam({ name: 'id' })
  @Delete('/:id')
  public async deleteLabelOne(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Param('id') id,
  ): Promise<void> {
    try {
      return await this.taskService.delete(id);
    } catch (error) {
      throw ErrorHandlerHelper.errorHandler(error, req);
    }
  }
```

How do i change it to delete all records at once?

Comment: Based on the used annotations I assume you're using nestjs - do you mean how you'd create a route in your nestjs-controller for deleting all users or what is the exact problem here?

Comment: Yes, you correctly understood my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to simply add a new delete-route that does not accept a single id, e.g:

```
 @Delete('/deleteAll') // or whatever you'd like to call your new route
 public async deleteAll(@Req() req: Request) {
    try {
      return await this.taskService.deleteAll(); // add a new method in your service to delete all entries
    } catch (error) {
      throw ErrorHandlerHelper.errorHandler(error, req);
    }
  }
```